# How to pass parameter using navigation.navigate at a Functional Component to another Functional Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, navigation

I am trying to pass values from one Functional Component to another Functional Component on navigation.navigate, on the first screen the value is there I can see it rendering it or on console.log, but when I try to get it on the second screen I get it "undefined".
Here I pass the value to the navigation.navigate:

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress = {() => navigation.navigate('AuditS',{audit:r.id})} style={styles.button}>
```

I will post my code bellow, if someone can give me a help I'll really appreciate it.

First Component:

```
import React, { createElement, useState, useEffect  } from 'react';
import { Text, StyleSheet, View,TouchableOpacity,Image} from 'react-native';
import AuditButton from './component/AuditButton'
import axios from 'axios' 

const HomeScreen = ({ navigation }) => {

const [checklists, setChecklists] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
axios.get("http://100.13.16.113:8081/api/checklists", {      
              }).then
              (function (response) {
                setChecklists(response.data);
                console.log(response.data);

              }).catch(error => {
                console.log(error);                        
              })
},[]);

return (
<View >
   <Text style={styles.text}> Select an Audit</Text>

  <View style={styles.maincontainer}>
      <View style={styles.container}>
      {checklists.map(r =>(

        <TouchableOpacity onPress = {() => navigation.navigate('AuditS',{audit:r.id})} style={styles.button}>
          <Image source={require('../assets/icons8-audit-80.png')} 
            style={styles.Image}>
          </Image>     
      <Text style={styles.ButtonText}>{r.checklisT_DESCRIPTION}{r.id}</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity >
        ))}
      </View>
  </View>
    <View style={styles.bottomcontainer}>
    <TouchableOpacity onPress = {() => navigation.navigate('Login')}     
    >
    <Text style = {styles.logout}>LOGOUT</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
</View>

);
};
```

Second Component:

```
import React, { createElement, useState,Component } from 'react';
import { Text, TextInput, StyleSheet, 
View,TouchableOpacity,Image,ScrollView,Modal,TouchableHighlight} from 'react-native';
import {Collapse,CollapseHeader, CollapseBody} from 'accordion-collapse-react-native';
import AuditItem from './component/AuditItem'
import RNPickerSelect from 'react-native-picker-select';
import AuditCategory from './component/AuditCategory';



const AuditScreen = ({ audit, navigation}) =>
{
const [modalInfoVisible, setModalInfoVisible] = useState(false);
const [opNumber, setOP] = useState(false);
const [FGINumber, setFGI] = useState(false);
const [checklistitems, setChecklistitems] = useState([]);
const auditId = audit;
console.log(JSON.stringify(auditId));



return ()
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest  you to use react-router-dom if you are working with router.

Answer (score 0):

make some changes in second component like

```
const AuditScreen = () => //some changes in line
 {
 const {audit} = navigation.state.params;  //added line
const [modalInfoVisible, setModalInfoVisible] = useState(false);
const [opNumber, setOP] = useState(false);
const [FGINumber, setFGI] = useState(false);
const [checklistitems, setChecklistitems] = useState([]);
 const auditId = audit;
console.log(JSON.stringify(auditId));
return ()
```

Hope it helps!!!

Comment: I've changed the code to the way you told me, but now I'm getting error "TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'route.params')"

Comment: what is your react navigation version?

Comment: The version at the package.json is this:
  "react-navigation": "^4.3.9",

Comment: ok changes I have tell is for version 5, wait I will change according to 4.

Comment: Updated the code to suggested way, but got the same error. 

**
const AuditScreen = () =>
{
    const audit = this.props.navigation.state.params.audit;  //added line

    const [modalInfoVisible, setModalInfoVisible] = useState(false);
    const [opNumber, setOP] = useState(false);
    const [FGINumber, setFGI] = useState(false);
    const [checklistitems, setChecklistitems] = useState([]);
    
    
    const auditId = audit;
    console.log(JSON.stringify(auditId));


  
    return ()**

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215244/discussion-between-shan-alam-and-tiago-martins).

Comment: Thanks to @Shan Alam answers, I could find how to pass the value from one Functional Component to another using version 4.x of navigation.navigate.
On second screen I've had to add  this:    `const {audit} = navigation.state.params;`